# How can I manage roles from resource instance perspective by rolify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multi-tenant, rolify

I'm trying to create a multi-tenant app and I'm use rolify gem to manage roles
here are my relationships of models

1. User can have multiple tenants.
2. Tenants can have multiple users.
3. Tenants can have multiple documents.

```rb
class Tenant
  has_many :members
  has_many :users, through: :members
  has_many :document
end

class User
  has_many :members
  has_many :tenants, through: :members
end

class Document
  belongs_to :tenant
end
```

and I want to add some roles to manage tenants and documents
according to documentation, I should implement like below

```rb
# add role to manage tenant
user.add_role(:admin, Tenant.find(1))
user.add_role(:member, Tenant.find(2))
```

```rb
# add role to manage document
user.add_role(:edit, Document.find(1))
user.add_role(:view_only, Document.find(2))
```

but I'm wondering can I separate roles table by different resources
something like this

```rb
class Tenant
 rolify :role_cname => 'TenantRole'
end

class Document
 rolify :role_cname => 'DocumentRole'
end

tenant = Tenant.find(1)
tenant.add_role(:admin, User.find(1))
tenant.add_role(:admin, User.find(2))

document = Document.find(1)
document.add_role(:editor, User.find(1))
document.add_role(:view_only, User.find(2))
```

the reason that I want to do this way it's because
I'm assuming users might have many tenants and also belongs to different tenants,
at the same time, users might have different roles for each document in tenants
if I always add roles from the user perspective, I'm worried about do I adding too much data to a table (Role table) and it might cause
performance issue when I do queries, another reason is I think separate role table by resources is easier to manage role for resources

does any advice for this case? thanks

Comment: My advice here is don't use Rolify - this is beyond the scope of what its designed to do and you'll just be fighting it. It a nice little tool for simple use cases but it uses a single roles table and a HABTM association so you can't query the join table directly. It also uses a polymorphic association which can limit eager loading. Its quite easy to just set up a series of discrete tables and replicate the needed functionality.

Comment: My second piece of advice is don't shove everything into your roles system - use Pundit to encapsulate your authorization logic and don't implement everything as a role as it creates a god class.